# Calculating $ \sum_{n \ge 3|m|}^{} (-1)^n q^{(2n + 1)^2 - 32m^2} $.

Tags: calculus

$ \sum_{n \ge 3|m|}^{} (-1)^n q^{(2n + 1)^2 - 32m^2} = η(8t)η(16t)$.
(Kac-Peterson)

I try to confirm the formula, however I don't know the left.
(The right is $q -q^9 -2q^{17} + q^{25} + 2q^{41} + \cdots $)

Define $a(k)$ as the following.

> $ \sum_{n \ge 3|m|}^{} (-1)^n q^{(2n + 1)^2 - 32m^2} = \sum a(k) q^{k}.$

For example,

$(2n + 1)^2 - 32m^2 = 1$ and $n \ge 3|m|⇔ (n, m) = (0, 0)$. So $a(1) = (-1)^0 = 1.$

How do we calculate $a(9), a(17), \cdots$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_triple_product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(2n + 1)^2 - 32m^2 = 9$ and $n \ge 3|m|⇔ (n, m) = (1, 0)$.

So $a(9) = (-1)^1 = -1.$

$(2n + 1)^2 - 32m^2 = 17$ and $n \ge 3|m|⇔ (n, m) = (3, -1), (3, 1)$.

So $a(17) = (-1)^3 + (-1)^3 = -2.$

The other $a(k)$ is calculated by the same way.